# Can I set the width of UIWebBrowserView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView on iPad and its frame is `CGRect(0, 0, 540, 620)`.

When it opens a page it appears like this.

[image]

The web content is large than my frame. (web content in blue border)

I found the view in blue border is UIWebBrowserView.

So, can I set the UIWebBrowserView's width via my web view?

Or, is there other ways to make my web page content to fit my web view size?

Comment: hi, how did you resolve this? I have same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to zoom out the content (using the `scrollView` property of `UIWebView`) or set an appropriate `meta` tag with a correct `viewport`, so that the content appears in the correct size.